# Можно ли сделать так, чтобы меню опций выглядело одинаково во всех браузерах?

Tags: html, css, select

Всем привет.
На фото все наглядно видно. Извиняюсь, если не смог в загаловке правильно отобразить суть вопроса. 
В идеале эта полоса должна выглядеть как верхняя на скриншоте(хром). А вот в других браузерах не айс. В Сафари вообще адский ад. 
Так вот, их вид как-то можно изменить? Хотел через css, однако поле выбора опций и сама 'морковка' это, как оказалось, один единственный html-элемент, и я этим немного смутился...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Стандартные элементы лишь ограниченно можно менять через css, поэтому есть сторонние библиотеки элементов (например, jquery-ui или bootstrap) - они скрывают стандартный элемент, заменяя его своими на основе  и листов стилей.

Если ты хочешь, чтобы в разных браузерах такие элементы выглядели одинаково, то придется использовать подобные библиотеки или создавать свои.

Я использую, например, jquery-ui, но с переделанным оформлением (просто залез и изменил .css файл под свои нужды).